# Getting RequireJS to work with .mu

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm using requireJs for my application and I have instances where I'm loading .js files, and at some instances I'm loading templates with the .mu extension and I'm trying to work on getting the requirejs not to automatically append .js and end up trying to load template.mu.js.

I also tried using the noext plugin but i end up getting this error when i use that plugin:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

it highlights the `<div id="content">` in the template.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yobsdoa6/2/

Is there any way to tell RequireJS to not do this?Thanks

Comment: @Tomasz:  i dont think it is duplicated, the one you mentioned above is asking a way to load mustache templates in requirejs. I know the way, however i have issues while loading the .mu files using the text plugin that im trying to solve in this thread? If im wrong, please explain how does that thread solve my problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insted of `noext` plugin try to use [text](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html#text) plugin.

`noext` probably try to load a `JavaScript` file. `text` load file as-is.

`noext` is for dynamic scripts, `text` is for templates.

Example usage:

```
define(['text!libs/template.mu'], function(tmpl) {
    //some code here
});
```

Comment: Well, text plugin is what I have been using all this time to load my mustache files, but requirejs adds this .js extension at the end of mustache files only, hence i tried using the noext plugin. Is there any other alternative you know off that would prevent the ext?

Comment: I personally use `Handlebars` (Mustache on steroids) with `require-handlebars-plugin`. Works fine.

Comment: Run this: https://github.com/tomi77/requirejs-test